# [roscpp] unsubscribe within a callback and resubscribe in while(ros::ok)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, as new to ros and c++, I have a question to ask about unsubscribe and resubscribe. I am working on a multi-quadrotor path planning project and need to define squad leader everytime the team split into new squads. In that case, the squad member will subscribe to its leader for further commanding. But I have trouble on how to unsubscribe old leader's command and resubscribe to a new leader's. Below is the part of code that doing this little function:

```
ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub;
// get split command from the leader and determine leader(s) for squad(s)
void getsplitcmd(const geometry_msgs::Point::ConstPtr& msg)

{

//...some code to find out whom to follow

squad_leader_no = ...;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "mycontrol_4");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Rate cycle(8); 

while(ros::ok()){

 // ...some other code here

  if(squad_leader_no == 1){splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav1/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);}

  if(squad_leader_no == 2){splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav2/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);}

  if(squad_leader_no == 3){splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav3/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);}

  if(squad_leader_no == 4){splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe("/uav4/split_cmd", 1000, getsplitcmd);}

// ...some code here

  ros::spinOnce();

    cycle.sleep();

  }
  return 0;
}
```

After a numerous tests, only once I have the subscriber resubscribed. At other times, it just seem not to work at all(no disconnection and reconnection). Also, I have tried `splitcmd_sub::shutdown()` within the callback, but it just did not work.

I have searched and read a lot of tutorials and questions by other people online, it seems that I will have to use `boost::bind` if I want to pass parameters from callback to while() in main everytime it receives new messages. Could anybody tell me what to do if I want to unsubscribe a topic and resubscribe to another one at correct times, please?
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190273/%5Broscpp%5D-unsubscribe-within-a-callback-and-resubscribe-in--while(ros::ok)/) by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-14**:
to be more clear, the publisher split_cmd has been defined and publishing in the same .cpp file

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-14**:
try using `if-else` to ensure in one loop only one call back and `splitcmd_sub::shutdown()` inside callback.

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-14**:
I have tried those, but it did not work

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-15**:
It was my own mistake that caused the problem, and sorry about that! Anyway, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks a lot for your time, t.pimentel!!! I have found where I did wrong, and it was a careless mistake. The comparison I made between squad_leader_no and integer value was in different format. Sorry about wasting your time. :/

---

Originally posted by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) with karma: 30 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
subscribe() returns a Subscriber object that you must hold on to until you want to unsubscribe. When all copies of the Subscriber object go out of scope, this callback will automatically be unsubscribed from this topic.
```

So it should work to just resubscribe to another topic, is squad_leader_no a global variable? Is its value being changed?
If it's not working to just resubscribe, you can try to unsubscribe by doing:

```
splitcmd_sub.shutdown();
```

Your code would be something like (it's usually better to have local variables, so I changed squad_leader_no to local):

```
ros::Subscriber splitcmd_sub;
void getsplitcmd(const geometry_msgs::Point::ConstPtr& msg, int *squad_leader_no)
{
  splitcmd_sub.shutdown();
  //...some code to find out whom to follow
  *squad_leader_no = ...;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "mycontrol_4");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Rate cycle(8);
  
  int squad_leader_no = INITIAL_LEADER;

  while(ros::ok()){
   // ...some other code here

    if(squad_leader_no == 1){
      splitcmd_sub = n.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Point>("/uav1/split_cmd", 1000, boost::bind(getsplitcmd, &squad_leader_no, _1) );
    }
    if(squad_leader_no == 2){ repeat }
    if(squad_leader_no == 3){ repeat }
    if(squad_leader_no == 4){ repeat }

    // ...some code here

    ros::spinOnce();
    cycle.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) with karma: 385 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-14**:
yes, the squad_leader_no is a global variable so far and its value changes. I will try your code first and let know if the problem has been solved. Thank you.

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-14**:
hi t.pimentel, I have tried boost::bind and defined squad_leader_no as local, but still got the same results, topics were not chosen and resubscribed then. But when I put 'uav1/split_cmd' as initial condition before while(ros::ok()) and remove all the if statements in while(), it could successfully be shut down.

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-14**:
I am wondering if the frequency the loop spinning will be a potential reason causing this problem, like it needs time to proceed received data before subscribing again.

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2014-08-15**:
Did you try to use a flag to only enter the if statements if there was a change?

```
if( squad_leader_no != old_squad_leader_no ) {
    if(squad_leader_no == 1){
        //do something
    }
}
```

**Comment by [PJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/19993/pj/) on 2014-08-15**:
well, it does not help, either. The weird thing is, it could unsubscribe using shutdown() within callbacks and removing all those if statements in while(). But once I wanted it to resubscribe with if statements in while(), it seemed no unsubscribing and resubscribing happened, it just stayed on initial subscription.